# Java findout if current platform supports windowing

Tags: java, user-interface

Is there way to find out if Java is running on a platform which supports windowing of any kind? I know that you could possibly figure it out by reading in the environment variables, but that might prove to be rather difficult with all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()
```

(see also the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#isHeadless%28%29))